# Linux: Read words from file enclosed in quotation

Tags: linux, file, command

I have a file where the first line looks something like this:

```
"Window Size" "Param 1" Result Time
```

So it basically has some words separated by spaces. I need a Linux command that will read the word at a specific position, where words enclosed in quatation marks should be seen as one word (and returned without the quatation marks).

So if I execute the command with the number 1 (doesn't matter if it starts from 0), the following should be returned:

```
Window Size
```

If executed with 3, it should return:

```
Result
```

Any idea how to do this, with awk maybe?

Comment: from line 2 one, the data looks differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the name of your file containing your data is `test.txt`. One possible solution in BASH with arrays:

```
eval "E=( $(cat test.txt) )"
echo ${E[0]}
echo ${E[2]}
```

The output is:

```
Window Size
Result
```